# Adding empty playlist with pyspotify

Tags: python, spotify

So this is the library I'm using for talk to Spotify is pyspotify(https://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/)

My question is regarding having spotify pick up on changes I make. For example I do the following.

```
config = spotify.Config()
config.user_agent = 'My awesome Spotify client'
config.tracefile = b'/tmp/libspotify-trace.log'
ses=spotify.Session(config)
ses.login('name','pw',remember_me=True)
ses.process_events()

while ses.connection.state!=1:
    ses.process_events()
    time.sleep(1)
print "connected"

container=ses.playlist_container
while (not container.is_loaded):
    x=container.load(10)
    print x

v=x.add_new_playlist("exampleyo")
print x
```

I first print my entire playlist which contains my 2 default playlists

```
PlaylistContainer([Playlist(u'spotify:user:majesty:playlist:7DnzJS82m7AlmAxP7oKpfc'),
 Playlist(u'spotify:user:playlistermaker:playlist:2IEaPJeW5CrApb2zClrNd2'))
```

I then add a new playlist, then print out my playlists again,

```
PlaylistContainer([Playlist(u'spotify:user:majesty:playlist:7DnzJS82m7AlmAxP7oKpfc'),
 Playlist(u'spotify:user:playlistermaker:playlist:2IEaPJeW5CrApb2zClrNd2'),
 Playlist(u'spotify:user:playlistermaker:playlist:3B1maHfMyNawj5Xp4cabrm')])
```

My program then terminates. I guess my expectation at this point is that I should see a new empty playlist named exampleyo to appear on my spotify. It isnt coming up.

I feel like there must be some sort of push to the spotify server, but I can't seem to find it. I didn't know if the reason I cannot see this is because the playlist is empty, it will only upload if there is something in there, or I'm just not pushing it. I feel like this is pretty trivial, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears with this library that you cannot add an empty playlist. When I looked further, I.E made a playlist with songs in it, syncing happened instantly.